# Why are WCF services only working when I remove endpoints?

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf, endpoint

We've got several services that, in development, are set to run using Local IIS. In the web.config of each service project is, among other things, the endpoint for the service. This works both in development and in production.

Yesterday I setup the development environment on my laptop, but I am having a very odd issue with the services. I get a 400 error when I try to navigate my browser to any of them, and I tried a number of things to get them to work but ultimately I found that if I deleted the endpoint from the web.config then they would work. This is quite the opposite of how it is on my desktop and on other developers' machines where the endpoint has to be present for the service to run.

This makes absolutely no sense to me, and at this point the only difference I know of is that my laptop is running on Windows 7 whereas all the other machines are on Windows 8.

Can anyone explain how a service will only work when the endpoint is defined on one pc, but on another pc it will only work when the endpoint is not defined? Definitely baffled by this one.

EDIT:

On my local development machine (specifically, my laptop with Windows 7) I have taken everything out of the web.config but what is essential to making the webpage that says "You have created a service. To test this service ... etc." come up successfully. This is what remains:

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="LOG_WCF_CALLS" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The "LOG_WCF_CALLS" AppSetting is obviously not necessary in general but just for our service because it looks for it in a static constructor. And the serviceMetadata tag allow me to navigate to the service using a web browser and see the "You created a service." page but otherwise wouldn't be necessary to actually use the service. So without those two things there would actually be nothing in the web.config at all. I don't understand how it's possible that this service comes up when I navigate to it though when there are no end points defined anywhere??

Comment: What account do you run app pools as on both machines?

Comment: @zaitsman On the development machines it just runs under the default app pool. On the QA and Production environments there is an app pool specifically for the services. What are you thinking... how might that affect the end points?

Comment: Can you post the `<system.serviceModel>` section from the config file on your local machine?